# SSL Certificate issue while accessing web service in Production

Tags: web-services, ssl

This isssue in an live environment. We communicate with a webservice in our .net application for a purpose. Most of the time the call is successfull but sometimes it fails with the below message.|

Any idea where the problem could be?

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.#Level:Error
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.#Level:Error

---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Is it really you communicating with the webservice or is there some kind of technology involved? If yes, what would that be?

Comment: Hi @piet.t, ours is a .net application and we communicate with a third party webservice which is hosted via SSL